# How to get the IP address from an authentication event?

Tags: laravel, laravel-10

I have a few authentication events with listeners, for example `'Illuminate\Auth\Events\Failed'`: https://laravel.com/api/10.x/Illuminate/Auth/Events/Failed.html

I want to get the IP address from it, but since there is no request here I cant use `$request->ip()`.

Is there any way to pass the request to the event?

Comment: Create your own event class and store the IP with the event. Access it from the listener. Don't rely on `request()` helper, events are handled asynchronously and the helper will just return the last request handled.

Comment: Oh true didn't think about it being async as in my environment I use it with the sync queue so completely forgot about it. I can then simply copy the event source code and add the request then dispatch. Do you know at what point in the login process in the LoginController I should dispatch my custom event from? I'm going to have to override the entire AuthenticatesUsers trait also in order to be able to place it in the right place

Comment: Yeah it can be a bit frustrating having to override multiple classes to do minor things. But in this case you should just be able to override `AuthenticatesUsers::sendFailedLoginResponse()` in the controller, and fire your event from there. That method is even passed an instance of `Request`...

Comment: So `use AuthenticatesUsers {sendFailedLoginResponse as traitSendFailed;}` and then implement `protected function sendFailedLoginResponse(Request $request)` in your controller, making sure to call `$this->traitSendFailed()` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure if it would be the "Laravel way" but perhaps you can try to add a middleware to store the IP, so you can retrieve later at the listener.

```
php artisan make:middleware name_of_your_middleware
```

Middleware:

```
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $request->ipAddress = $request->ip();
    return $next($request);
}
```

Register the middleware at `Kernel.php`

And use it in the routes you need.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'name_of_your_registered_middleware'], function () {
    // Routes that need to store the IP address
});
```

In your authentication event listener, you can access the stored IP address using the $event object:

```
public function handle(Failed $event)
{
    $ipAddress = $event->request->ipAddress;
}
```

Hopefully works for your case!

Comment: I was also about to do something complicated. But someone reminded me that I can simply use the `request()` helper: `request()->ip();` 

Comment: I was about to say that when I first read the thread, but from my understanding it was you couldnt access at all the request, either object or helper. Anyway, I'm glad that you solved it !

Comment: What do you think `$event->request` is? Where is it set?